# Squash 2 commits into 1

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have two commits locally:

```
commit adae40c5e2b69a41447b08cc3dcb77003611fbbe
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Mar 21 14:17:35 2019 +0000

    1.0.0

commit ceaa65ea06f48dc24554a6f798aae2d668f3a43d
Author: Me
Date:   Fri Feb 1 10:04:36 2019 +0000

    first commit
```

How do I squash these so there is only one commit with the message `1.0.0`?

I tried the following but neither has worked for me:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
git rebase -i master
```

Comment: Did you change the `pick` to `squash` for the second commit in the opening editor window?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+first+commit

Comment: In your specific situation, RomainValeri's answer is probably the simplest solution.  However, it may be useful to understand why interactive rebasing isn't working for you, because rebase is a much more powerful / more general tool and will work in many cases where simply reset + commit will not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those not fond of interactive rebasing, in a situation like this it's also quite easy to just rewind and recommit :

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Rebasing is an especially helpful feature in Git but it will not squash commits, it will do the opposite and preserve each commit. The `reset` then `commit` process you laid out is perfect for squashing the commit history.

Comment: @benhorgen You're right. It's unclear from my answer but I did refer to *interactive* rebasing (then choosing `squash` where it should) rather than "normal" rebasing.

Comment: @benhorgen - I'm not sure what you mean.  A rebase can indeed squash commits. It is true that the original commits are preserved (at least temporarily) after any rebase, but the same is true of the rebase-and-recommit method.